# Trying to move e2e code into a function with no success

Tags: protractor, e2e-testing

The problem is due to promise resolution, I pass in an xPath for all elements to be searched along with a string to search for and I would like the element returned. Here is the code:

```
export class Library {
  static findListItem(xPath: string, findItem: string): any {
    let z = 0;
    const allItemsXPath = xPath.split('[X]');
    const itemXPath = xPath.split('X');
    console.log(xPath + ' : ' + findItem);
    const itemList = element.all(by.xpath(allItemsXPath[0] + allItemsXPath[1])).map(function (item) {
      return item.getText();
    });
    itemList.then(function (itemText) {
      console.log(itemText.length);
      for (let k = 0; k < itemText.length; k++) {
        itemFound = true;
        console.log(itemText[k] + ' : ' + findItem);
        if (itemText[k] === findItem) {
          z = k + 1;
          console.log('found ' + z);
        }
      }
    }).then(() => {
      console.log(itemXPath[0] + z + itemXPath[1]);
      // element(by.xpath(itemXPath[0] + z + itemXPath[1])).click();
      return element(by.xpath(itemXPath[0] + z + itemXPath[1]));
    });
  };
```

The commented line for clicking works. It can see the element and click on it. I would like to return the element to the caller who would then click.

If the return isn't in a .then section then the return happens too quickly and z = 0. The way it is now, nothing is returned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your function `findListItem` no return value, Add `return` before `itemList.then`

```
static findListItem(xPath: string, findItem: string): any {
   ...

   return itemList.then(function (itemText) {
      ...
   });
}

Library.findListItem(xxx, yyy).then(function(item){
   return item.click();
})
```

I have a question on your below code which to find the matched item, you compare one char of `itemText` with a whole string `findItem` per iterate. Are you sure you can find the matched one with below code.

```
 for (let k = 0; k < itemText.length; k++) {
    itemFound = true;
    console.log(itemText[k] + ' : ' + findItem);
    if (itemText[k] === findItem) {
      z = k + 1;
      console.log('found ' + z);
    }
  }
```

Comment: The function is returning value using 'any' in the function header. What is going on with itemlist is the lines above it where it is defined grabs all of the values in a dropdown list and using .map, converts the promises into an array of text. The itemlist.then you mention makes it wait for promise resolution so no return goes there. itemList is an array of strings so itemList[k] is a string, not a character. Hope that makes sense

Comment: You indeed declared the return value type for the function, but you didn't give  any explicit  `return` statement for the function,  double check this. so when you invoke `findListItem()`, it returns `undefined`.

Comment: Thank you, that helped a lot. Although it returns a promise so after after calling the function with const obj = <function call>     I then have to use obj.then(function(elem) {
      elem.click();
    }); Is there a way to return the obj after promise resolution? if not, this will work and thank you again Yong!

Comment: It's no way to return a non-promise in your case.

Comment: I understand and thank you again. You have resolved my problem.